# many2one field not showing field values

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, many-to-one, openerp-7

Im having a problem linking a many2one field to another many2one field. Im getting numbers like 1,2,3(i think its the record number) instead of the field value in the drop down list.

Below, I have 3 classes Activity code, Activity data, and Activity summary.

Activity summary has a many2one field called 'activity_code' that relates to  Activity data and activity data has a many2one field that relates to activity code. I am able to see the field values in the drop down list in activity data form, it works fine, but im not able to view it in Activity summary form. I get single digit numbers

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how i may fix it to show the intended value instead of the numbers? Below is my code.

Activity code

```
class activity_yearcode(osv.osv):
 _name = "budget.activity_code"
 _description = "Activity Year Code"
 _rec_name = "activity_code"
 _columns = {
    'activity_code' : fields.char("Activity Code", size=64, required=True),
    'activity_name' : fields.char("Activity Name", size=128),
    'act_status' : fields.selection([
                ('1', 'All'),
                ('2', 'Active'),
                ('3', 'Inactive'),
                ], 'Status'),
    }
_sql_constraints = [
    ('activity_code_unique', 'UNIQUE(activity_code)', 'Each activity code is unique.'),
]
```

Activity Data - working fine

```
class activity_data(osv.osv):

_name = "management.activity_data"
_description = "Activity Data"
_rec_name = "activity_data_num"
_columns = {
    'activity_data_num' : fields.char('activity_data_num', size=16),
    'activity_code' : fields.many2one( "budget.activity_code","Activity Code",required=True),
    'management_unit_code' : fields.many2one("budget.org_table","Management Unit Code", required=True),
}
_defaults = {
    'activity_data_num': lambda self,cr,uid,context={}: self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'management.activity_data'),
}
_sql_constraints = [
    ('activity_data_num', 'UNIQUE(activity_data_num)', 'Each activity_data_num is unique.'),
]
```

Activity Summary - In this model, im getting a single digit number in drop downl list instead of the the field value in 'activity_code' field.

```
class activity_summary(osv.osv):
_name = "work.activity_summary"
_description = "Activity Summary"
_columns = {
    'activity_code' : fields.many2one("management.activity_data", "Activity Code", ondelete= "no action", required=True ),
    'management_code' : fields.related("activity_code", "activity_data_num", "management_unit_code", type = "char", string = "Management code"),
'region_id' : fields.char("Region ID", size=64, required=True),
    'daily_prod' : fields.integer("Daily Prod"),
    'deviation' : fields.integer("Deviation Level"),

             }
```

Please help..Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code,

```
class activity_summary(osv.osv):
    _name = "work.activity_summary"
    _description = "Activity Summary"
    _columns = {
        'activity_code' : fields.many2one("budget.activity_code", "Activity Code", ondelete= "no action", required=True ),
        'management_code' : fields.related("activity_code", "activity_data_num", "management_unit_code", type = "char", string = "Management code"),
        'region_id' : fields.char("Region ID", size=64, required=True),
        'daily_prod' : fields.integer("Daily Prod"),
        'deviation' : fields.integer("Deviation Level"),
    }
```

And your other code is OK. Please try this class if you have any problem to get values just ask.

Hope this will help you get value.

Comment: ,hi, sorry, but there's no change,

Comment: `class activity_summary` field name `activity_code` is in relationship with `management.activity_data` and `management.activity_data` has `_rec_name = 'activity_data_num'` in your case. `_rec_name` should be `'activity_code'` as i given in answer, and other solution like you can change relationship with `class activity_summary` field name is `'activity_code' : fields.many2one("budget.activity_code", "Activity Code", ondelete= "no action", required=True ),`

Comment: I have changed the _rec_name to 'activity_code', and its linking correctly and working fine, but when i run it, i can't see the activity code i created earlier for example "AC001" in the fields drop down instead i see only a single digit like 3,  on the other hand, if i change the relationship like you said, 'activity_code' : fields.many2one("budget.activity_code", "Activity Code", ondelete= "no action", required=True ), it works perfectly fine. thank you and  much appreciated

Comment: have you solved your problem than i will edit my answer and you may accept that ?